# How do I match a div's height to another divs perspective height?

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

What I am trying to achieve is matching the middle div's height to the right side of the left div's height & left side of the right div's height.

I have tried scale which works to start but if you adjust the window size the scale doesn't match.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#div1 {
    padding: 50px;
    width:15%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    transform:     perspective(13.5em) rotateY(5deg);
}

#div2 {
    padding: 50px;
    width:15%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: blue;
    display: inline-block;
}

#div3 {
    padding: 50px;
    width:15%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    transform:     perspective(13.5em) rotateY(-5deg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's increase the angle of rotation so that it's easier to see the problem.

Now, the solution: you want the inner edges of the rotated elements to match the size of the non rotated element.

Just set the transform origin to this border. This way, the said border isn't moving, and it matches naturally the size of the inner div

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: perspective(13.5em) rotateY(30deg);
  transform-origin: right center;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: red;
  transform: perspective(13.5em) rotateY(-30deg);
  transform-origin: left center;
}

div {
  width: 15%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div2"></div>

<div id="div3"></div>
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I need, I had no idea about the origin property... thanks!

Comment: Happy that it helped you !

Answer (score 2):

Here you go.

```css
#div1 {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: perspective(13.5em) rotateY(5deg);
}
#div2 {
  padding: 48px;
  width: 15%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
#div3 {
  padding: 50px;
  width: 15%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  transform: perspective(13.5em) rotateY(-5deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>

<div id="div2"></div>

<div id="div3"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks ok at smaller resolutions but if I span the window across 3 monitors 7680 pixels wide, the middle div's height is larger than the inside of the other 2 divs. It's something to do with how perspective works and would be great if I could apply a percentage perspective to the middle div without the rotate.

Comment: Yeah. I can see it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/9ys3hkfe/

If the rotation of the other two `div` will change, then you'll have to calculate their edges' heights based on the amount of rotation, and then apply that the the middle div's padding and margin-bottom.

Comment: I believe you have mistaken the links

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Didn't you? I just thought you did, because your solution is almost the same as mine. Even exactly the same. :P

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I didn't take your link though, our minds obviously work in the same way!

Comment: Seems like. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library: http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Is very easy to use for example:

HTML:

```
<div id="div1 equal-height"></div>
<div id="div2 equal-height"></div>
<div id="div3 equal-height"></div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.equal-height').matchHeight({
    byRow: true,
    property: 'height',
    target: null,
    remove: false
});
```

Regards!

Comment: Thanks Radames, I'll have to look into this. Just guessing before though that this will match the height of the highest point whereas I'm looking to match the inside edge height of the outer divs (the smaller sides).

Comment: You can use the property target, is an optional element to use instead of the element with maximum height.